# Script not working in subsequent modals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got help with a script that works in the first modal but doesn't in any of the next couple. When you scroll down, the background color changes in the first modal but nothing happens in the second and so forth.

https://jsfiddle.net/qhrmtass/10/

```
var scrollFn = function () {
var targetOffset = $("#anchor-point")[0].offsetTop;
console.log('Scrolling...');

if ($('.remodal').scrollTop() > targetOffset) {
    $(".projectTitle").addClass("topper");

} else {
    $(".projectTitle").removeClass("topper");
       }
};

$('.remodal').scroll(scrollFn);
```

Comment: You have to use a unique `id` check `anchor-point`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Specification says UNIQUE**
>
> [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id) says ID must be document-wide unique.
>
> [HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute) says the same thing but in other words. It says that ID must be unique in its *home subtree* which is basically the document if we read the definition of it.

1. First for the best practice you have to change duplicate id `anchor-point` (in my example i change it to class) also for the id `one` should be unique.
2. Secondly you have to use `$(this)` inside your scroll function `scrollFn` to detect the current scrolling `remodal` and to select the elements that belong to it.

**HTML :**

```
<a class="project-link" href="#modal1" id="one" style="margin-right:25px;">Modurra Shelving </a> 
<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal1">
    
    <div class="dar">Darrien Tu.</div>
    <button class="remodal-close" data-remodal-action="close"></button>
    <div class="anchor-point">sdfsfs</div>
    <div class="title">
        <p class="projectTitle">Modurra
            <br>Shelving.</p>
    </div>
        
        
</div> <a class="project-link" href="#modal2" id="one" style="margin-right:25px;">Other stuff </a> 
    
<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal2">
    <div class="dar">Darrien Tu.</div>
    <button class="remodal-close" data-remodal-action="close"></button>
    <div class="anchor-point">sdfsfs</div>
    <div class="title">
        <p class="projectTitle">Modurra
            <br>Shelving.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Js :**

```
var scrollFn = function () {
    var targetOffset = $(this).find(".anchor-point")[0].offsetTop;
    console.log('Scrolling...');
    
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > targetOffset) {
        $(this).find(".projectTitle").addClass("topper");

    } else {
        $(this).find(".projectTitle").removeClass("topper");
    }
};

$('.remodal').scroll(scrollFn);
```

Hope this could help, take a look at **[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qhrmtass/11/)**